# Is there any compiler / compressor library suitable for Javascript 1.7 and particularly Firefox extensions?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xpcom, google-closure-compiler, uglifyjs

- I have looked through Google Closure Compiler and found [this](http://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#I%27m_writing_a_Firefox_extension._It_only_needs_to_work_on_t). it
  doesn't like "const", "let" and other Javascript 1.7 tags.
- UglifyJS also seems to miss support for Javascript 1.7.
- YUI Compressor doesn't accept ECMASCRIPT features like getters/setters

Is there any compressor which supports Javascript 1.7 features nowadays? The only thing that i need is clearing comments/whitespaces (WHITESPACE_ONLY analogue of GCC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to rewrite JavaScript used by Firefox extensions you better use the same JavaScript engine. There is a JavaScript rewriting engine called [JSHydra](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSHydra). Originally it required you to compile SpiderMonkey, this is no longer necessary thanks to the [Parser API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Parser_API). You can get one of the precompiled [JavaScript shell nighlies](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-trunk/) (the `jsshell-OS-ARCH` archives) and run a [simple script](https://hg.adblockplus.org/jshydra/file/8b63cf16c671/jshydra.js) through it (the script does exactly the same as the original JSHydra binary):

```
js jshydra.js scripts/astDecompile.js scriptToRecompile.js > recompiled.js
```

This will make the JavaScript engine parse your script and then run `scripts/astDecompile.js` (a script that is part of JSHydra) to decompile it back into JavaScript code. Comments will be removed "automatically" (JavaScript engine doesn't keep them) and the decompiled code won't have much whitespace other than newlines. The newlines are easy to get rid of if you need it.

Note that the [official JSHydra repository](http://hg.mozilla.org/users/Pidgeot18_gmail.com/jshydra) has a bunch of decompilation bugs so you might want to use [my fork](https://hg.adblockplus.org/jshydra/) instead.

Comment: Thank you. That's definitely what i was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

Btw currently we switched to [escodegen](https://github.com/Constellation/escodegen), which has pretty nice support for all moz-* specific features and even has flags for them. Actually I made a couple of pull requests to support muptiple catch statements, MemberExpression, moz-specific GeneratorExpression etc.

The only thing which out project is missing is support for LetStatement, SpiderMonkey's AST for LetStatements is sometimes really strange and its logic differs from ES Harmony's. PR for moz-specific LetStatements is [here](https://github.com/Constellation/escodegen/pull/155)

So we are now building our extension now with escodegen's master branch and LetStatement's PR branch placed on top of master.